# Refactoring out functional differences in complex calculations in Ramda

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm just starting to play with Ramda a bit, and I'm relatively new to functional programming in general. I'm starting to get the hang of how to structure my programs, but I keep getting hung up on a certain aspect. I feel that I must be missing some key concept.

I'm not even certain of how to word my question, so I am going to start with an example. This code snippet is a portion of the calculation for the centroid of an arbitrary polygon:

```
var centroidX = R.converge(
                    R.divide,
                    R.compose(
                        R.sum,
                        R.map(
                            R.converge(
                                R.multiply,
                                R.converge(R.add, x1, x2),
                                diffOfProducts
                            )
                        ),
                        makeVertexPairs
                    ),
                    sixTimesPolyArea
                );
var centroidY = R.converge(
                    R.divide,
                    R.compose(
                        R.sum,
                        R.map(
                            R.converge(
                                R.multiply,
                                R.converge(R.add, y1, y2),
                                diffOfProducts
                            )
                        ),
                        makeVertexPairs
                    ),
                    sixTimesPolyArea
                );
Geom.centroid = R.curry(function(vertices) {
                    return [ centroidX(vertices), centroidY(vertices) ];
                });
```

Notice that the only difference between `centroidX` and `centroidY` is that the X coordinate calls `x1` and `x2` near the middle, and the Y coordinate calls `y1` and `y2` near the middle.

Is there some simple way to refactor out this commonality such that I can do something like the following:

```
var centroidCoord = R.converge(
                    R.divide,
                    R.compose(
                        R.sum,
                        R.map(
                            R.converge(
                                R.multiply,
                                R.converge(R.add, R.__, R.__),
                                diffOfProducts
                            )
                        ),
                        makeVertexPairs
                    ),
                    sixTimesPolyArea
                );
Geom.centroid = R.curry(function(vertices) {
                    return [ centroidX(x1, x2, vertices), centroidY(y1, y2, vertices) ];
                });
```

I know that this isn't even close. I'm just trying to express what I want to accomplish. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering in a hurry, so I may be missing something simple.  But is there a reason that it has to be entirely points-free?

Why not just

```
var centroid = (coord1, coord2, vertices) => R.converge(
// ...
                        R.converge(
                            R.multiply,
                            R.converge(R.add,coord1, coord2),
                            diffOfProducts
                        )
// ...
)(vertices);

Geom.centroid = R.curry(function(vertices) {
    return [ centroid(x1, x2, vertices), centroid(y1, y2, vertices) ];
});
```

Comment: Ha! Well, don't I feel silly. Of course, that makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: I'm a big fan of points-free code.  But I think we often make too much of a fetish of it.  A well-placed anonymous function will often make things much clearer.  And sometimes it's more straightforward at the top level too.